# Sparx Enterprise Architect integration with HP ALM

Tags: integration, enterprise-architect, alm

I'd like to import requirements from EA into HP ALM to be able to join them with test cases. EA provide import to XML but I do not see, do not know any compatible option in HP ALM to import these data.

Would you please geive me any hint regarding integration of EA and HP ALM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [page](http://blog.bpm-x.com/?p=276) BPM-X has a solution to link EA and HP ALM.

If that doesn't do what you need you can still write something yourself. 
You could write an add-in for EA, use scripts in EA, or use the CSV export and start from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the add-on idea.